# Compile files from URLs in table as zip

Tags: files, theming, importing-exporting

I've got a Views table with a column displaying links to files (images, pdf's etc.). I've got a button below the table that exports the entire table. I need another button that should start a .zip download of all images currently shown in the table. The table has a filter on it, so it's important that only the files from the filtered results are downloaded.

I haven't been able to find a module or similar use case, so I hope there's someone here that can point me in the right direction.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Enable the PHP input filter and add a text area to the footer of your view, then use something like the following to build an array of all of your files (taken from [this tutorial](https://drupal.org/node/342132)):

```
<?php
function views_get_current_view_result() {
  $view = views_get_current_view();
  return $view->result;
}
?>
```

And then use that array to build the zip according to [download multiple files as zip in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754352/download-multiple-files-as-zip-in-php)

This would be a lovely idea for a views display handler plugin module, which many would probably find useful.